# What are possible causes of a sudden drop in google serps for some (not all) queries?

Tags: seo

A site I manage has seen a sudden drop in visits from google.

It used to have about 300-500 daily visits until a week ago. They were 10% from a strong, competitive query; 80% were long tail queries.
Now I lost both, and visits dropped by 90%. I still have

There were no changes on the site for the last 3 months, and all changes since last year were trivial. I din't notice any PR changes lately.

What are possible causes of this?

I assume I wasn't banned, as I still have a couple of top ranking queries.

[edit] My pagerank didn't (apparently) change. I still have 4 in the homepage.

Comment: Since some might be interested: after four months the site rised again in search query, without intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe "Google dance" explains observed behavior: the indices do get updated in individual data centers separately, but once the update is finished (which takes less than a day, as far as I understand), you should expect consistent search results regardless of which of the Google data centers was hit.

The OP didn't say which site "suffered".

Maybe some human at Google looked at it and decided that it should be penalized for (spam, malware, MFA, or whatever)? Or there could now be new sites which "answer" both queries better.

Answer (score 1):

This is not google dance. We're experiencing the same thing. We went from first page to - non existant! Mostly on geographical search terms... But a few others are still ranked highly.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reason where site get down on Google SEO. I would advice you to see the Google webmaster first. Google Webmaster help you to check your site's health for potential issues that Google has detected. Follow this step to know if your site is totally drop in SEO.
-> Sign in to Google Webmaster account
-> Select your xyz.com website
-> Select the Google Index
-> Check the Index Status
if it total index is greater than 0 then your site is displaying in Google properly but there might be other reason which you have to check manually.
1. Is the site has duplicate content ? visit http://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content
2. Does your site effect by malware ? https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/rAeadZWRJ_8
3. There could be reason of www and non www. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/QkA8WjHSuCk
So on, I hope this will help

If you think all is fine and still site is not visible then you should submit your site for Google reconsideration. If your site is not appearing in Google search results, or isn't performing as well as it used to, it may be in violation of our quality guidelines. If you don't see your site in the list, add it to your account and verify site ownership.
Here is the direct link. ( https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/reconsideration )

Request reconsideration of your site:

1.Sign in to Webmaster Tools with your Google Account.
2.Make sure you have added and verified the site you want reconsidered.
3.Request reconsideration of your site.